# When to put XML declarations (elements containing information) for one module in system.xml and when in config.xml?

Tags: magento-1.9, module, ce-1.9.2.4

In Magento 1.9.2.4, I am seeing two XML documents in one of my modules, one is `config.xml`, other one is `system.xml`. What is the difference between the two, ie. what is system.xml for and what is `config.xml` for (except for declaring the module version, routes, and layouts)?

Comment: It depends. Magento 1 or 2?

Comment: Please see revised question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the `config.xml` file: this is the module configuration file. It contains:

- module version
- block declaration and rewrite
- model declaration and rewrite
- helper declaration and rewrite
- routes/controller declaration and rewrite
- translation file declaration
- layout file declaration
- event observer declaration
- cron jobs
- database resource declaration
- default configuration values

Take note of the last point as this one is related to the `system.xml` file. The only thing this file does is declaring new configuration fields under System > Configuration. You can define the default values using the `config.xml`